# Calling two services one after another in Angular using Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services

I am attempting to call two services on the ngOnInit in Angular I have the following code:

.ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Calling 1st service
    this.serviceOne.getAllServiceOneData().subscribe(
      data => (
        this.serviceOneData = data,
        console.log('successfully loaded all service one data')
      ),
      error => this.errorMessage =   error as any,
    );

    //Trying to call 2nd service
    if (this.serviceOneData.length > 0) {
      this.serviceOneData.forEach(so => {
        this.serviceTwo.getAllServiceTwoData(so.id.toString()).subscribe(
          data => (
            this.serviceTwoData= data,
            console.log('successfully loaded service two related data')
          ),
          error => this.errorMessage =   error as any,
        );
      });  //forEach
    }  //if
}
```

Now, I would like to subscribe to a second service and fetch the related information for each one of the items that was fetch on the first service.

Is that possible using observable in Angular? Btw, I am working with Angular 7.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `switchMap` and `forkJoin` like this (see the comments for the explanation):

```
this.serviceOne.getAllServiceOneData()
        .pipe(
          //Use switchMap to call another API(s)
          switchMap((dataFromServiceOne) => {
            //Lets map so to an observable of API call
            const allObs$ = dataFromServiceOne.map(so => this.serviceTwo.getAllServiceTwoData(so.id.toString()));

            //forkJoin will wait for the response to come for all of the observables
            return forkJoin(allObs$);
          })
        ).subscribe((forkJoinResponse) => {
          //forkJoinResponse will be an array of responses for each of the this.serviceTwo.getAllServiceTwoData CALL
          //Do whatever you want to do with this array
          console.log(forkJoinResponse);
        });
```

Instead of [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) you can also use [concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html) depends on your app need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why use switchMap? Won't it cancel the first call??

Comment: why is there a map??? omg so confusing

Comment: @user1034912 switchMap respects the most recent observable. If an observable is in progress and at the same time another value is piped in the observable chain, then the switchMap will use the most recent one. It is the nature of switchMap. If you want to process all values then you can user mergeMap.

Comment: @user1034912 In the example code above,`map` is a regular array method. Although there is a `map` operator as well in RXJS.